# How to use tint for vector drawable in compatibility mode?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

I'm trying to apply tint for ImageButton that uses vector drawable:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
           android:id="@+id/flashlight_button"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_flash_off_black_24dp"
           android:tint="@color/icon_states_color"
           />
```

This will work Lollipop +, but will crash on Kitkat.

How should do ColorList tint for Kitkat in app compat world?

Answer (score 0):

hi you can programmatically add tint in your image button and make check if it below lollipop then it work below aternate way.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:backgroundTint) the related method to `android:backgroundTint` is [setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList list)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.content.res.ColorStateList))

**Update**

Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) to know how create a Color State List Resource.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="#your_color_here" />
</selector>
```

then load it using

```
setBackgroundTintList(contextInstance.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.your_xml_name));
```

where `contextInstance` is an instance of a `Context`

---

using AppCompart

```
btnTag.setSupportButtonTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Activity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
```

Try this way, hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

android:tint within vector drawable with work. So just android:tint in layout should be avoided.